# Can't return array outside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js

I have a function

```
function gotData(data){
    result = data.val() 
    const urls = Object.keys(result)
                 .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 5)
                 .map(key => ({url: 's/price/' + result[key].url_site + '/'}))
}
console.log(urls)
```

But I can't `console.log(urls)` it show error as

```
ReferenceError: urls is not defined
```

How can I return `urls`?

Comment: Surprisingly, it's `return urls` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function gotData should return the urls,

```
function gotData(data){
    result = data.val() 
    return urls = Object.keys(result)
                 .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 5)
                 .map(key => ({url: 's/price/' + result[key].url_site + '/'}))
}
 console.log(gotData(yourdata));
```

Comment: 1) you never call the function, 2) the very pattern is awkward at best - why have another variable if you just can return the result in function and use the returned value outside?

Comment: sorry misundertood the question

Comment: still need to call the function